# Why I lost a string data on the deserialization step?

Tags: c#, properties

```
[Serializable] 
[DataContract(Name = "A", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
public sealed class A: B
{
   private readonly string _exportName = EnumLocalization.ExportType_Azure; // "Azure"

   // Added for serialization purposes
   public A() { }

   public A(string containerName, string folderName)
   {
      ContainerName = containerName;
      FolderName = folderName;
      Description = SafeFormatter.Format(Localization.Culture,
                                         VirtualizationLocalization.LocationDescription, 
                                         containerName + "/" + folderName,
                                         _exportName);
   }

   public override string DisplayExportTypeName {get { return _exportName;}
...

}

[Serializable] 
[DataContract(Name = "B", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
[KnownType(typeof(A))]
public abstract class B
{
    [DataMember(Name = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract string DisplayExportTypeName { get; }
}
```

When I call my constructor everything is OK. `Description` contains `Azure` string. But when I call `Request.Location.DisplayExportTypeName` it's return `null`.

If I marked `_exportName` like `private static readonly string _exportName` it's return `"Azure"`. WHY doesn't it work in first case?

Somehow I lost my data when transfer data between UI and backend (deserialization stuff)

On the UI side:

```
location = new A(exportModel.AzureContainerName, "folder");
// location.DisplayExportTypeName = "Azure"; _exportName = "Azure"
CoreClient.ExportSchedulerManagement.ValidateExportLocation(location);
```

On the backend side:

```
public void ValidateExportLocation(VirtualMachineLocation networkLocation)
{
     _exportSchedulerService.ValidateExportLocation(networkLocation);
}
```

`In networkLocation DisplayExportTypeName = null && _exportName = null`

I'm using WCF to transmit the data.

Why I lost my data?

Comment: On what instance do you call Request.Location.DisplayExportTypeName? An instance of class A or class B?

Comment: Where is the definition of `Description`? How does it look like? How do you call it?

Comment: Please show the code that yields the wrong results.  Fields are not inherited and cannot be overridden, so it's unclear what you're trying to "override"

Comment: @WicherVisser There can be no instance of type B, it is abstract.

Comment: Please show how you use this code. And please show your actual code, or a [mcve] that reproduces the problem exactly. Currently there's suddenly a `Request.Location` coming from nowhere.

Comment: There's nothing wrong here.  You're doing something else.wrong.  Create a small prototype that does this (in a console application) and prove it to yourself.  This may be caused by you referencing an older version of an assembly where you never set _exportName, or you might not actually be setting it to any value, or a few other possibilities.

Comment: Oh. These are DataContracts. There's a _lot_ more going on here that you don't show. If you're detecting the problem on the client side, it's because you've generated proxy classes that represent the shown structure, but not the implementation, for one.

Comment: What is `EnumLocalization.ExportType_Azure`? A constant? Another readonly property? How is `Request.Location` created? Through deserialization? What kind? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Could you please add details about how you are transmitting the data?  Are you using WCF?  Or is it some other method with a custom serializer?  With that in an [edit] this question will be answerable.

Comment: Updated. I'm using WCF